# query failing with syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

i tried with following query and i failed to count the duplicates
please help me out.

```
   SELECT id
        , Count(id) As theCount
     FROM (
           SELECT e.id
                , e.cont
                , e.date
                , p.fname
                , p.lname
                , p.phone_cell
                , p.phone_home
                , p.email AS Count
             FROM pdata AS p
                , ehistory AS e
            WHERE p.id = e.id
              AND e.date >=  '2007-08-05'
              AND e.date <=  '2019-08-10'
         ) As C
GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT Count(id) > 1
       ;
```

I'm receiving the error

> syntax to use near 'Count(id) > 1'

i assume everything is correct. if anything wrong help me out! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i'm getting error "syntax to use near 'Count(id) > 1' " @aleksey.berezan

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `COUNT` word from having as below

```
SELECT id, Count(id) As theCount
FROM ( SELECT e.id, e.cont, e.date, p.fname, p.lname, p.phone_cell, p.phone_home, p.email    AS Count
       FROM pdata AS p, ehistory AS e
       WHERE p.id = e.id
       AND e.date >=  '2007-08-05'
       AND e.date <=  '2019-08-10') As C
       GROUP By id
HAVING Count(id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using 'COUNT' two times

Try this

```
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```

Instead of

```
HAVING COUNT Count(id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using two COUNT. use this instead

```
      HAVING Count(id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Counts. Remove one:

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  COUNT(id) AS theCount 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    e.id,
    e.cont,
    e.date,
    p.fname,
    p.lname,
    p.phone_cell,
    p.phone_home,
    p.email AS COUNT
  FROM
    pdata AS p,
    ehistory AS e 
  WHERE p.id = e.id 
    AND e.date >= '2007-08-05' 
    AND e.date <= '2019-08-10') AS C 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING COUNT (id) > 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the alias name :::

```
SELECT id
        , Count(id) As theCount
     FROM (
           SELECT e.id
                , e.cont
                , e.date
                , p.fname
                , p.lname
                , p.phone_cell
                , p.phone_home
                , p.email AS Count
             FROM pdata AS p
                , ehistory AS e
            WHERE p.id = e.id
              AND e.date >=  '2007-08-05'
              AND e.date <=  '2019-08-10'
         ) As C
GROUP BY id
  HAVING theCount > 1
       ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try below query

```
SELECT Count(e.id) As theCount
            , e.id
            , e.cont
            , e.date
            , p.fname
            , p.lname
            , p.phone_cell
            , p.phone_home
            , p.email AS Count
         FROM pdata AS p
            , ehistory AS e
        WHERE p.id = e.id
          AND e.date between  '2007-08-05' AND '2019-08-10'
       GROUP BY e.id
       HAVING  theCount > 1;
```